# Отображение статистики о количестве дней проведенных в телеграм бот каждому пользователю

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

Есть База Данных Sqlite3 в которой хранится `user_id` и время его первого запуска бота `clock` дата хранитсся в unix timstamp.

Задача такова при отправке сообщения боту у пользователя должно отображаться его кол-во дней проведенных в боте.

```
import datetime
import time
import sqlite3


dt = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())

def get_time_user(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    count = c.execute("select clock from users where user_id = (?)", (user_id,))
    get_timestamp = count.fetchall()
    c.close()
    return get_timestamp[0][0]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def key(message):

    if message.text == 'Кол-во дней':
        get_date_with_bd = get_time_user(message.chat.id) 
        t = dt.fromtimestamp(timestamp - get_date_with_bd)
        days = t.strftime('%d')
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            'Ваше время проведенное в боте {0} дней' .format(
                (days)
            )
        )
```

Все вроде работает за исключением одного. Если дата первого запуска бота совпадает с текущей то выдает следующую ошибку

```
t = dt.fromtimestamp(timestamp - get_date_with_bd)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Если же прошло больше суток то бот отвечает!
Почему не хочет отображать день 0 либо 1?

Comment: лучше задать вопрос о конкретной ошибке: «при вызове fromtimestamp() получаю: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument» указав какое именно значение передаёте и на какой системе работаете¶ Для контекста можно упомянуть что вы пытаетесь достичь (найти число дней и что конкретно на входе, что на выходе). У вас несколько ошибок (простейший код мог бы выглядеть как `days=(time.time() - unix_timestamp_from_bd)//86400`)¶ Не нужно при получении OSError при вызове fromtimestamp() весь код, который у вас есть приводить [mcve]

Comment: Дело в том что я новичек и мне нужен развернутый ответ поэтому вопрос я задаю тоже развернуто дабы при ответе могли скоординировать куда что впихивать и исправлять

Comment: новичок или нет, в любом случае  следует по одной проблеме за раз, а не всё в кучу решать. И главное, более сфокусированный вопрос больше шансов и у других людей встретится (назначение Stack Overflow — это библиотека решений, а не тренировочный лагерь)

Comment: дак это мне пересоздать вопрос?

Comment: достаточно, нажать кнопку [edit] под вопросом.